# Correct way to install Mercurial on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, version-control, mercurial

I am kind of new to both, Mercurial and Ubuntu.

I seem to have awkwardly installed a few other software packages already, so I wanted to see how others would go about doing this.

Should I use the apt-get command? If so, how would I use it in this case? Where is the best place to install Mercurial on my file system, and how do I make it part of my shell (I am thinking svn-ish) so I can properly check things in and update?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: You should *always* use `apt-get` or whatever is the native package manager of the current platform unless you can't or have a very good reason to do otherwise.

Comment: belongs on Ask Ubuntu in my opinion.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Just use:

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
```

It should install it in the default folder and update your environment variables correctly.  then you should be able to use 'hg' from the command line, just like svn, although Hg is a much better source control tool.

Comment: Somehow amazingly enough that worked lol.  Now how do I configure/use it? :)

Comment: @Genadinik: The beautiful thing about package managements already does everything for you. You just go and use the `hg` command from a shell.

Comment: configure it?  if you want to start a repo use 'hg init'.  If you want to customize the repository edit hgrc file.

Answer (score 63):

**NEW ANSWER**

Previously I was pointing to TortoiseHG PPA, which also contained Mercurial. For now (year 2015) the more recent version of Mercurial is in another PPA, specific for Mercurial only.

*Important note: this version is incompatible with TortoiseHG, and Tortoise will be REMOVED, if you install the more recent Mercurial!*

If you don't care of Tortoise and just want more recent Mercurial package, use next command to install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:mercurial-ppa/releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mercurial
```

However, this won't give you the absolutely latest version either. To enjoy the latest version, you may want to install it via PIP:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev
sudo pip install mercurial --upgrade
```

This would give you the very latest version (3.6.2 vs 3.3.2 from the PPA). Seems this one is also not compatible with TortoiseHG from the repos.

---

**OLD ANSWER**

Though available from default repos, the version there is outdated. At the time of writing: 2.2.2 vs 2.5.2. So I would recommend to use the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:tortoisehg-ppa/releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mercurial tortoisehg
```

TortoiseHG is not required, but is recommended.

Comment: For Ubuntu 10.04 this gave me a **much** newer version than the default package.

Comment: On 12.04 this gave 2.8.2 instead of 2.0.2!! **Huge** difference!

Comment: On 20.04 and just running `sudo apt install mercurial` without adding PPAs installed v5.3.1

Comment: This is much more useful than the accepted answer! On Xenial, this gave me the most recent version 5.5.1 instead of a hugely outdated version 3.1.3.

Comment: This is unfortunately super old now and not useful on any recent version of Ubuntu :( I wish it wasn't so hard to install later versions of things on Linux. On Windows I just download whichever installer I want, but on Linux I don't get to choose unless I want to build from source, which is a pain.

Answer (score 12):

Yeah you can install it by just

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
```

but for me it gave very old version (2.0.2). You can check this by `hg version`. To get the newer version you can do

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build-essential
sudo easy_install -U mercurial
```

Now I have 3.0.1 version

```
aniket@ubuntu:~$ hg version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 3.0.1)
(see http://mercurial.selenic.com for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2014 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

More details : [Installing Mercurial on Linux](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2014/07/installing-mercurial-on-linux.html)

PS: Above link goes to my personal blog which has additional details.

Comment: I just wanted to say that "apt-get install mercurial" wasn't updating to the latest version (even though it said it was doing so). This solution finally worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Mercurial is available from the Universe repositories.
Enable that repository in USC if it's not already enabled.
Then just type the following into a terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install mercurial
```

The configuration file is saved in /etc/mercurial/hgrc
You can configure mercurial by editing that file.
To open that file in gedit type the following command

```
sudo gksudo gedit /etc/mercurial/hgrc
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using an older version of Ubuntu (12.04 perhaps?), use the [Mercurial PPA](https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/releases).

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mercurial-ppa/releases
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mercurial
```

As of this writing, this installs mercurial 3.0.1 on Ubuntu 12.04 for example.

Answer (score 3):

just to let everyone know,
 `sudo apt-get install mercurial` 
is delivering version 3.0.1 (latest as the time of writing this post)
 so no need to try other stuff as this is everything you'll need.

Comment: in what version of ubuntu?

Comment: lubuntu 14.04, I believe in ubuntu should be the same.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be true for regular Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

The Mercurial version in the Ubuntu repository is relatively old. I tried to use the PPA, to get more recent version. But Ubuntu complains that "The repository ... does not have a Release file" and disables it.
Then I used alternative way to install latest Mercurial version:

```
sudo pip3 install mercurial --upgrade
```