# How can I get the keyring extension working for mercurial in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: mercurial, ubuntu-18.04, mercurial-keyring

I've tried dozens of guides on installing mercurial and keyring extensions on Ubuntu and have never been able to get the keyring extension to work.  It was a snap under Windows.

I've installed mercurial many different ways.  I'm not sure if the install method has anything to do with the keyring, but here are a few of the things I've tried:

- `sudo apt-get install mercurial`
- `sudo apt install mercurial`
- `pip install mercurial`
- ... and so on.

I even used [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15773831/782880) where it compiles mercurial.

All of these methods work for mercurial.  It runs.  I can do commits, etc.  It's `keyring` and `mercurial_keyring` installations that are giving me trouble.  I installed both of those using `pip install`.  When I do a command like:

```
hg out http://somerepo
```

At the moment, I'm getting the following message:

> No handlers could be found for logger "keyring.backend"

I feel like there is a concise set of steps to get keyring working, but it's just eluding me.  I've made half a dozen attempts on fresh virtual machines and can never get this to work. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
pip uninstall keyring
```

The reason is that python has already the library **python-keyring** installed which conflicts with the one installed with pip. Credits to [Python library woes on Ubuntu 18.04 by Kai Koenig](https://medium.com/@kaikoenig/python-library-woes-on-ubuntu-18-04-32c6828b5f56)

Edit: the story actually did not end there because what it did was to get rid of that error but was not the actual solution. I had to continue with these commands

```
pip install keyrings.alt
pip install keyring
```

(yes, I installed it back)

```
python -c "import keyring.util.platform_; print(keyring.util.platform_.config_root())"
```

That was taken from [keyring docummentation](https://pypi.org/project/keyring/#id9). It turned out that my config folder shown by this command was not created so I did:

```
mkdir ~/.local/share/python_keyring
vi ~/.local/share/python_keyring/keyringrc.cfg
```

I had to create the .cfg file as well and put this inside (on my MacOS Mojave!):

```
[backend]
default-keyring=keyring.backends.OS_X.Keyring
```

Now everything works fine, no password asked anymore